# generate modal with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i have a modal and i want to show it only with javascript
i have a button

```
<button onclick='ShowModal'>LOGIN </button>
```

when i click on button this code will run

```
$("#myModal").modal();
```

and i have a modal in html

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content" style="direction: rtl">
            <div class="modal-header" style="padding:35px 50px;text-align: center; font-size: 30px;">
                <h4>برای دیدن پروفایل کامل وارد شوید یا ثبت نام کنید</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" style="padding:40px 50px;">
                <h3><strong>ورود به شهوانی</strong></h3>
                <br>
                <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="4gGY6LdmQsOvV6X2U20RnaOZ1v0nwXGI">
                <p>
                    <label for="id_username">نام کاربری:</label>
                    <input id="id_username" maxlength="254" name="username" type="text">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="id_password">گذرواژه:</label>
                    <input id="id_password" name="password" type="password">
                </p>
                <input class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" type="button" onclick="SendToHost()" value="ورود">
                <input type="hidden" name="next" value="">

                <p>پسوردتان را فراموش کرده اید؟ <a href="/accounts/password/reset/">بازنشانی کنید</a></p>
                <p>عضو نیستید؟ <a href="/accounts/register/">ثبت نام کنید</a>!</p>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer" style="background-color: #f9f9f9;">
                <div class="row">
                    <br>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
                        <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline">
                            <li><a href="/">خانه</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/tos">قوانین</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/faq">راهنما</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/privacy">حریم خصوصی</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/contact">تماس</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/accounts/login/">ورود</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

but i want to generate in javascript and dident use it in page
i mean when i click on button java script generate modal and show it not show a ready html modal

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement

Comment: @Teemu searching for fast way

Comment: `createElement` is very fast. More code is also more performance on this case.

Comment: @Teemu It isn't fast at all when you're trying to do this job.

Comment: @MARSHMALLOW Please show me a benchmark.

Comment: Yes there are ways to do it, but what are you trying to achieve exactly? Why do you want a dynamic modal?

Comment: @hosein Are you familiar with Ruby? Because a part of my answer is in Ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
function CreateModal(){
  var html = [
//you can change code to your html
for creating you can use [this site][1]

            '<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">',
            '    <div class="modal-dialog">',
            '        <div class="modal-content" id="Main-Modal">',
            '            <div class="modal-header" style="padding:35px 50px;text-align: center; font-size: 30px;">',
            '                <h4>برای دیدن پروفایل کامل وارد شوید یا ثبت نام کنید</h4>',
            '            </div>',
            '            <div class="modal-body" style="padding:40px 50px;">',
            '                <h3><strong>ورود به شهوانی</strong></h3>',
            '                <br>',
            '                <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="4gGY6LdmQsOvV6X2U20RnaOZ1v0nwXGI">',
            '                <p>',
            '                    <label for="id_username">نام کاربری:</label>',
            '                    <input id="id_username" maxlength="254" name="username" type="text">',
            '                </p>',
            '                <p>',
            '                    <label for="id_password">گذرواژه:</label>',
            '                    <input id="id_password" name="password" type="password">',
            '                </p>',
            '                <input class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" type="button" onclick="SendToHost()" value="ورود">',
            '                <input type="hidden" name="next" value="">',
            '                <p>پسوردتان را فراموش کرده اید؟ <a href="/accounts/password/reset/">بازنشانی کنید</a></p>',
            '                <p>عضو نیستید؟ <a href="/accounts/register/">ثبت نام کنید</a>!</p>',
            '            </div>',
            '        </div>',
            '    </div>',
            '</div>',


        ].join("\n");
        $("body").append(html);
//here you force modal to be open
        $("#myModal").modal({"backdrop": "static"});
}
```

and on your button

```
<button onclick='CreateModal()'>LOGIN </button>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need a function that loads the modal into the DOM, *and* a function to make it visible.

```js
const myModalDiv = "<!-- all your modal HTML markup goes here -->";
let modalLoaded = false;
function loadMyModal() {
  if (modalLoaded) { return; }
  document.body.appendChild(myModalDiv);
  modalLoaded = true;
}

function showMyModal () {
  if (!modalLoaded) { loadMyModal(); }
  $('#myModal').modal('show');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `document.getElementById('wrapper').innerHTML = "<div>contents</div>";`.
This method will be a little annoying, but
here's a solution: you can write your modal's HTML code in a separate file, then you make a simple utility in Ruby (for example) to delete all the line breaks from your file.
Here's an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

File.open("htmlfile.html", "r") do |f|
   File.new("output.js", "w")
   File.open("output.js", "w") do |ff|
      contents = f.read()
      contents["\n"] = "" # Remove the line breaks
      ff.write(contents)
      ff.close()
   end
f.close()
end
```

Open the file called "output.js" and you'll find your "parsed" HTML code!
Now you can insert it into your javascript file.
Here is your code:

```js
$("#_button").click(function() {
   document.getElementById('form_wrapper').innerHTML = '<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog"><div class="modal-dialog"><!-- Modal content--><div class="modal-content" style="direction: rtl"><div class="modal-header" style="padding:35px 50px;text-align: center; font-size: 30px;"><h4>برای دیدن پروفایل کامل وارد شوید یا ثبت نام کنید</h4></div><div class="modal-body" style="padding:40px 50px;"><h3><strong>ورود به شهوانی</strong></h3><br><input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="4gGY6LdmQsOvV6X2U20RnaOZ1v0nwXGI"><p><label for="id_username">نام کاربری:</label><input id="id_username" maxlength="254" name="username" type="text"></p><p><label for="id_password">گذرواژه:</label><input id="id_password" name="password" type="password"></p><input class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" type="button" onclick="SendToHost()" value="ورود"><input type="hidden" name="next" value=""><p>پسوردتان را فراموش کرده اید؟ <a href="/accounts/password/reset/">بازنشانی کنید</a></p><p>عضو نیستید؟ <a href="/accounts/register/">ثبت نام کنید</a>!</p></div><div class="modal-footer" style="background-color: #f9f9f9;"><div class="row"><br><div class="col-xs-12 text-center"><ul class="list-unstyled list-inline"><li><a href="/">خانه</a></li><li><a href="/tos">قوانین</a></li><li><a href="/faq">راهنما</a></li><li><a href="/privacy">حریم خصوصی</a></li><li><a href="/contact">تماس</a></li><li><a href="/accounts/login/">ورود</a></li></ul></div></div></div></div></div></div>';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="_button">Click on me!</button>
<div id="form_wrapper">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
// Create a new element in dom
var myModelHtml= $('#myModel').html();
$(document.body).append(myModelHtml);

// trigger Click model
$(myModelHtml).modal('show');

//  Remove model
$('div#myModal').modal("hide");
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <template id=myModel>
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">

                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content" style="direction: rtl">
                    <div class="modal-header" style="padding:35px 50px;text-align: center; font-size: 30px;">
                        <h4>برای دیدن پروفایل کامل وارد شوید یا ثبت نام کنید</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body" style="padding:40px 50px;">
                        <h3><strong>ورود به شهوانی</strong></h3>
                        <br>
                        <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="4gGY6LdmQsOvV6X2U20RnaOZ1v0nwXGI">
                        <p>
                            <label for="id_username">نام کاربری:</label>
                            <input id="id_username" maxlength="254" name="username" type="text">
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <label for="id_password">گذرواژه:</label>
                            <input id="id_password" name="password" type="password">
                        </p>
                        <input class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" type="button" onclick="SendToHost()" value="ورود">
                        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="">

                        <p>پسوردتان را فراموش کرده اید؟ <a href="/accounts/password/reset/">بازنشانی کنید</a></p>
                        <p>عضو نیستید؟ <a href="/accounts/register/">ثبت نام کنید</a>!</p>

                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer" style="background-color: #f9f9f9;">
                        <div class="row">
                            <br>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
                                <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline">
                                    <li><a href="/">خانه</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/tos">قوانین</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/faq">راهنما</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/privacy">حریم خصوصی</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/contact">تماس</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/accounts/login/">ورود</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </template>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi here is another workaround.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>

#adddiv {
display: none; 
text-align: center;
width: 80%; /*border-radius: 25px;*/ 
border: 2px solid Black; 
padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px; 
margin: 20px 20px 20px 20px; 
//background: #fff//#A4D3EE; 
overflow: visible; 
box-shadow: 5px 5px 2px #888888; 
position: relative; } 
#xadd { position: absolute; 
background: yellow; 
color: black; top: -10px; 
right: -10px; }
#add { position: absolute; 
background: #3caea3;//#3c99dc; 
color: white; }

#deldiv {
display: none;
text-align: center;
width: 80%; /*border-radius: 25px;*/ 
border: 2px solid Black; 
padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px; 
margin: 20px 20px 20px 20px; 
//background: #fff//#A4D3EE; 
overflow: visible; 
box-shadow: 5px 5px 2px #888888; 
position: relative; }
#xdel { position: absolute; 
background: blue; 
color: white; top: -10px; 
right: -10px; }
#del { position: absolute; 
background: red;//#3c99dc; 
color: white; }
</style>
<script>
function myFunctionaddopen() {
var x = document.getElementById("adddiv");
if (x.style.display !== "none") {
  x.style.display = "block";
} else {
    x.style.display = "block";
      }
    }
    </script>
<script>
function myFunctionaddclose() {
var x = document.getElementById("adddiv");
if (x.style.display === "none") {
  //x.style.display = "block";
} else {
x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>

<script>
function myFunctiondelopen() {
var x = document.getElementById("deldiv");
if (x.style.display !== "none") {
  x.style.display = "block";
} else {
    x.style.display = "block";
      }
    }
    </script>
<script>
function myFunctiondelclose() {
var x = document.getElementById("deldiv");
if (x.style.display === "none") {
  //x.style.display = "block";
} else {
x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click the action buttons below to open the modals:</p>

<button id="add" onclick="myFunctionaddopen()">button_1</button>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
<button id="del" onclick="myFunctiondelopen()">button_2</button>

<div id="adddiv">
This is the first modal Exit by clicking on the "x" button at the top right coner.
<button id="xadd" onclick="myFunctionaddclose()">x</button>
</div>

<div id="deldiv">
This is the second modal Exit by clicking on the "x" button at the top right coner.
<button id="xdel" onclick="myFunctiondelclose()">x</button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76334608/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).